# How to pull data from MySQL Database Table in MS-SQL Database Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Suppose I have a table A in MySQL,
and I have a table B in MS-SQL

I want to write a query in MS-SQL, that can help me apply join between tables A and B to get some data.

Is there any way to achieve that?

(I need a MS-SQL query for fetching the data, in SSMS, not in MySQL like you mentioned in duplicate)